# AWK help to cut some value from a line

Tags: awk

I want to print/cut string from file which contains something like below

```
I want to support CH: UTF-8 fully in my web application
I want to support CH: UTF-8 fully in my web application
I want to support UTF-8 fully in my web application
I want to support UTF-8 fully in my web CH:application
I want to CH:support UTF-8 fully in my web application
```

Output required

```
CH: UTF-8
CH: UTF-8
CH: application
CH: support
```

Comment: Sorry but it is not clear, please wrap up your samples in CODE TAGS. Also please do add your effots in your post which you have put in order to solve your own issue.

Comment: Sorry missed the formatting. Thanks Ed.

Comment: I would like to print the characters until next space following the match CH: . New to awk . I tried cut but would like to do with awk

Answer (score 0):

I get that you want someone to give you awk code to do the job, but that is unlikely because of how this site works. I'll try to get you started with the pseudocode:

Something like:

1. get a record
2. if any field in that record is "CH:" then print that field and the next one
3. repeat until end of file

With awk, steps 1 and 3 are free and do not require you to write any code. Take a stab at step 2 and see if you can do that. Once you submit your attempt(s) and any errors or discrepancies, folks are far more likely to be able to assist.

You might want to brute force it and check to see if $1 is "ch:", then check to see if $2 is "ch:" and so on until $NF. But I promise you that you will get much more useful assistance if you tell people what you have tried so far.

Note: my suggestion is inefficient, but somewhat intuitive for a beginner. I am hopeful that I did not make a mistake guessing OPs experience level.

Comment: Thanks let me try...want an output same as  grep -oP 'CH: .*?]' <filename>

Comment: I tried awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { if ($i == "CH:") { print $i, $(i+1)}} <filename> and it is close. It does not work when colon does not have a space immediately after, but I cannot tell if that is a requirement or not. If it is, you might have to change the FS values.